# Remove Daemonset pod from a node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running `DaemonSet` which is running on all nodes. I want to remove it from a node in order to completely drain it, as `kubectl drain` doesn't get rid of them. Without deleting my `DaemonSet`, what's a good way to temporarily remove those pods from the node? I've tried draining it and deleting the `DaemonSet` pods, but the `DaemonSet` will still reschedule them, disregarding that the node is set as `Unschedulable: true`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use `--ignore-daemonsets` key when you drain kubernetes node:

> --ignore-daemonsets=false: Ignore DaemonSet-managed pods.

So, in order to drain kubernetes node with `DaemonSets` in cluster, you need to execute:

```
kubectl drain <node_name> --ignore-daemonsets
```

If you need to **Remove DaemonSet pod from a node completely**, you can specify a `.spec.template.spec.nodeSelector` in `DaemonSet` (the DaemonSet controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node selector) and set that label to all nodes except the one you need to completely drain.

Comment: If the node is unused and needs to be removed , Would it make sense to just remove the nodegroup altogether ?