# Kubernetes: How to gracefully delete pods in daemonset?

Tags: kubernetes

If there is an update in the docker image, rolling update strategy will update all the pods one by one in a daemonset, similarly is it possible to restart the pods gracefully without any changes the daemonset config or can it be triggered explicitly?

Currently, I am doing it manually by

`kubectl delete pod <pod-name>`
One by one until each pod gets into running state.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use [Node maintenance operations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#maintenance-on-a-node):

> Use kubectl drain to **gracefully terminate all pods on the node** while marking the node as unschedulable (with [`--ignore-daemonsets`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078350/6309), from [Konstantin Vustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9065705/konstantin-vustin)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866960/kubernetes-how-to-gracefully-delete-pods-in-daemonset#comment92649044_52867165)):

```
kubectl drain $NODENAME --ignore-daemonsets
```

> This keeps new pods from landing on the node while you are trying to get them off.

Then:

> Make the node schedulable again:

```
kubectl uncordon $NODENAME
```

Comment: The `DaemonSet` controller ignores unschedulable markings, so a pod that belongs to a `DaemonSet` will be immediately replaced. If there are pods belonging to a `DaemonSet` on the node, the drain command proceeds only if the `--ignore-daemonsets` flag is set to true, but even if that is the case, it won’t delete the pod because of the `DaemonSet` controller.

Comment: @KonstantinVustin So delete the DaemonSet first, then recreate it after draining the node?

Comment: You will have to use flag `--ignore-daemonsets`, just because there will be `kube-system` namespace DaemonSets on each node, e.g. `flannel` or something else. So you don't need to delete user-defined  DaemonSets, because `kubectl drain` will not proceed without this flag anyway. The only thing you can do is modify NodeSelector filter in the DaemonSet to exclude it from the Node which should be drained

Answer (score 0):

To trigger restart of all pods managed by deamonset in namespace [namespace_name]:

```
 kubectl rollout restart de -n [namespace_name]
```